# Firebase Auth Get User Country

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth with google sign in and facebook sign in

Is there any other way to know which country the user is coming from ?

After The app know from which country the user is coming from, then the app will decide which service / future will be shown to the user.

Comment: There are many way to get user country code. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps

Comment: +Vikash Kumar Verma. I need it based on google plus / facebook profile. Because, mobile phone configuration not always based on which country the user live. I use english in my mobile phone but not live in english.

Comment: See my answer any let me know if it help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Try this code. This code will return country code based on which country's network it is connected to. [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso()). It won't work without SIM card.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

**Method 2:**
If your device is connected to internet you can use this link  http://ip-api.com/json . It will automatically detect ip address of device  return location details based on ip address.

**Method 3:** You can get location from GPS.

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
Location curLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation((double)curLocal.getLatitudeE6(),(double)curLocal.getLongitudeE6(),1);
String countryCode= addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
```

Comment: Good answer. I pick this as an answer of my question because it's solve my problem although the method is the alternative way instead of using firebase. I will choose the method 2 to be implemented in my app, because the app need internet connection. For method 1, not always user uses sim card. For method 3, it needs GPS permission. Thanks

Comment: In many cases, ip-api.com will only detect the location of the user’s s  proxy server. If they are using a VPN service then this will likely be outside their country.

Comment: @Plugie can you please guide me how to extract country using 2nd link method?

Comment: @AnkitMishra 
Unity 2019: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html
Unity 2020:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html

Comment: @Plugie you should be careful when using method 2. It's not free for commercial usages as mentioned in their website.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is great but changing providers, I use it like this:

```
await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json'));
```