# Fetch country code in Android if there is no sim card available in Phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps, search, development-environment

How to fetch user country code in android programmatically? I have to show payment in Indian rupees for Indians and in dollars for foreigners but I am not to fetch the user current country. If I use Locale, in some of the mobiles even though they are Indians it is returning US. Please suggest ways using Android.

Method 1: Using the telephone manager

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

But it won't work if there is no sim card in mobile.

Method 2:

```
 Locale.getDefault().
```

It is returning wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps Check above links.

Comment: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

Comment: @sagar patel I have tried the same method from the link , but it is not working if there is no simcard in the testing mobile.

Comment: @Gowtham M Please understand the question what I have asked. I want to fetch country code from device . I don't want user to select manually.

Comment: @SirishaCh ya no need to select country code by default it will set your country code and it will return your country code....one more thing if sim is not present in your mobile  cannot get the country code