# Get device country without using Location

Tags: android

I want to get the user's device **country** and **without** using GPS and any sensitive data.

By using `TelephonyManager::getSimCountryISO()`, I can get the country depending on the SIM card. But sadly that doesn't work if the device doesn't have a SIM (e.g Tablet).

Using the IP is a nice answer, but alot of users now use VPNs and Proxies which change the device IP, there for giving a false answer to where the device is.

The location **is** the most accurate answer, but there is still things such as *fake location*, and user's location is a very sensitive data to ask for, even for once.

> **P.S:** All `Locale` answers will be deleted or down voted, any
>   developer would know  that the Locale is user defined not device
>   defined. Same thing about Timezones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i get my android device country code without using GPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current location of user in Android without using GPS or internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694391/get-current-location-of-user-in-android-without-using-gps-or-internet)

Comment: Yes, but either of these questions and their answers aren't 100% right. And both of them are very old.