# How do apps like Telegram and Twitter automatically detect country dialing codes without asking for location permissions?

Tags: android, flutter

I am building a flutter app and I am asking the user to enter their phone number to get started with signup on the landing page just after the splash screen. I do not wish to ask location permission at this stage because I feel it will affect the user's experience.

I had a look at the Telegram and Twitter apps and noticed they are detecting the dialling code even without asking for android permissions.

I am assuming they get the users country and then based on that display the dialling code. But how do they get the country and is it legal to get the country code without asking for user's permission?

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i get my android device country code without using GPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess from your ISP/IP address?
There are API's available that can guess the country and more based on IP.

> https://ip-api.com/
>
> https://kickfire.com/api

Some ISP's are also only available in certain countries and they have a fixed range of IP addresses.

Comment: This solution best suited my requirement. Thank you for this info.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest to you is to import this package to your pubspec.yaml:
https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Then in Your code simply call:

```
final _countryCode = Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode;
```

It will get the country code of the device locale.
Didn't tested yet, but this method should work, enjoy :)