# Showing different content to different people from different countries

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I write the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293642/how-can-i-get-my-android-device-country-code-without-using-gps)

```
     context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getDisplayCountry()
```

but it doesn't get the user's country. it always shows my own country. when as a user, I use VPN from other countries and println the result, the result doesn't change. am I writing the correct code?

besides, I'm using KOTLIN. is the code the same in KOTLIN and JAVA in this case?!

I just want to find out the user's country, so I can show different content to different people. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're always getting the same country from the list because of `.get(0)`

Comment: thanks. I didn't know the meaning of the code. But when I remove it or remove the zero inside the parentheses, it gives an error. How should I change that code to become what I want?

Comment: @rezazeraati There are a couple of solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country).