# Getting Telephonic country code on starting app

Tags: android

I am trying to get the country **telephonic** code by reading **geolocation** on app start.

But I would get only **latitude** and **longitude**. How to get the telephonic code from geolocation.

I have done this far see :

First in String xml I would create an array like this

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>91,IN</item>
.....
.....
.....
</string-array>

public String GetCountryZipCode(){
    String CountryID="";
    String CountryZipCode="";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] rl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for(int i=0;i<rl.length;i++){
        String[] g=rl[i].split(",");
        if(g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
            CountryZipCode=g[0];
            break;  
        }
    }
    return CountryZipCode;
}
```

Now suppose I read geolocation but how would I know country name or country code(more easy if I get this)

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @HarisQureshi I am using sms gateway to send otp internationally okay?? and international number require telephone country code.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [getSimCountryIso](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso())

> Returns the ISO country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.

It has some (strange) behaviour have a look at [Unexpected getSimCountryIso() behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971806/unexpected-telephonymanager-getsimcountryiso-behaviour) for best experience you should use [Mobile country code (MCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code). You can find MCC in android using code below

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(networkOperator)) {
    int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
    int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
}
```

You can find MCC list [here](http://www.imei.info/operator-codes/) and [here](https://clients.txtnation.com/hc/en-us/articles/218719768-MCCMNC-mobile-country-code-and-mobile-network-code-list-). Save MCC list (from any of above links) in your application  and find country code by MCC or MCCMNC.

Comment: Harish but otp verification requires country phone code example - : 91 for India. I am having trouble to understand what MCC is?