# Android get Device Country Code

Tags: android

I want to get device country code with out using sim card.

e.g If Country : Sri lanka
       Country code : LK

my final goal is get calling code (+94 for sri lanka)

i tried with this

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

but this return empty string

Comment: USe these it might helpful for you:--TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()

Comment: may below link help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11872569/5352802

Comment: I tried with tm.getNetworkCountryIso(); but its return empty string. in my didn't have sim card.only wifi.

Comment: You can use this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=7.0000,81.0000&sensor=false for getting country code ..The short name will give you country code .. But you need to get the current lat and long ..

Answer (score 4):

It's returning an empty string because the device doesn't have a sim card.

You might be able to [use the device's current locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default):

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

but that's not necessarily going to be the same as what you'd get by looking at the carrier `iso` and the user can update that in the settings whenever they want to whatever they want. As pointed out, you can also ask the location manager for the user's coordinates. But remember, users move around and their current location may not always correspond to their carrier's `iso`.

Comment: Thanks fried. i tried this one also but it always return "US".

Comment: @ayeshdon that's because the local is set to US. I repeat, you ***cannot*** get the carrier `iso` *without* a sim card.

Comment: This will return the country of the Locale that the user configured. If the user configures the device for India and then takes it on a plane to Germany, you'll still get the country code for India. Just thought I would clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example. Try to get country code from TelephonyManager (from SIM or CDMA devices), and if not available try to get it from local configuration.

```
private static String getDeviceCountryCode(Context context) {
    String countryCode;

    // try to get country code from TelephonyManager service
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(tm != null) {
        // query first getSimCountryIso()
        countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length() == 2)
            return countryCode.toLowerCase();

        if (tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) {
            // special case for CDMA Devices
            countryCode = getCDMACountryIso();
        } else {
            // for 3G devices (with SIM) query getNetworkCountryIso()
            countryCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
        }

        if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length() == 2)
            return countryCode.toLowerCase();
    }

    // if network country not available (tablets maybe), get country code from Locale class
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        countryCode = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getCountry();
    } else {
        countryCode = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
    }

    if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length() == 2)
        return  countryCode.toLowerCase();

    // general fallback to "us"
    return "us";
}

@SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
private static String getCDMACountryIso() {
    try {
        // try to get country code from SystemProperties private class
        Class<?> systemProperties = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method get = systemProperties.getMethod("get", String.class);

        // get homeOperator that contain MCC + MNC
        String homeOperator = ((String) get.invoke(systemProperties,
                "ro.cdma.home.operator.numeric"));

        // first 3 chars (MCC) from homeOperator represents the country code
        int mcc = Integer.parseInt(homeOperator.substring(0, 3));

        // mapping just countries that actually use CDMA networks
        switch (mcc) {
            case 330: return "PR";
            case 310: return "US";
            case 311: return "US";
            case 312: return "US";
            case 316: return "US";
            case 283: return "AM";
            case 460: return "CN";
            case 455: return "MO";
            case 414: return "MM";
            case 619: return "SL";
            case 450: return "KR";
            case 634: return "SD";
            case 434: return "UZ";
            case 232: return "AT";
            case 204: return "NL";
            case 262: return "DE";
            case 247: return "LV";
            case 255: return "UA";
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ignored) {
    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also another idea is to try an API request like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753601/3680373), or to use [fine location](https://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/).

And in order to get country prefix you can use [LibPhoneNumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library from Google.

References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136339/3680373) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415296/3680373)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=7.0000,81.0000&sensor=false for getting country code ..The short name will give you country code ..

```
 public void getAddress(double lat,double lng) {
    Address1 = "";
    Address2 = "";
    City = "";
    State = "";
    Country = "";
    County = "";
    PIN = "";

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = JsonParser.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + ","
                +lng + "&sensor=false");
        String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
            JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject zero = Results.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray address_components = zero.getJSONArray("address_components");

            for (int i = 0; i < address_components.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject zero2 = address_components.getJSONObject(i);
                String long_name = zero2.getString("long_name");
                String short_name = zero2.getString("short_name");
                JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                String Type = mtypes.getString(0);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(long_name) == false || !long_name.equals(null) || long_name.length() > 0 || long_name != "") {
                    if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")) {
                        Address1 = long_name + " ";
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
                        Address1 = Address1 + long_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality")) {
                        Address2 = long_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                        // Address2 = Address2 + long_name + ", ";
                        City = long_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                        County = long_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                        State = long_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                        Country = short_name;
                    } else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                        PIN = long_name;
                    }
                }

                // JSONArray mtypes = zero2.getJSONArray("types");
                // String Type = mtypes.getString(0);
                // Log.e(Type,long_name);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But you need to get the current lat and long ..

Use this link for getting the current lat and lng

http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Comment: What if I'm not in my carrier's country?

Comment: He asked for the device country code without using sim card and this is the only option I guess. And you are right ,if user's carrier country and current country are different then  this won't work.

Comment: Sometime between then and now Google changed it to require an API KEY to be added to the URL.  It will look something like `&key=...` if tacked on the end.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()` is returning empty as i have two sim slots, you can pass slot as parameter if it returns `""`. Simply change your code to:

```
 String iso=telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso();
       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(iso))
           iso=telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso(1);
       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(iso))
           iso=telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso(2);

// this code will give preference to Sim Slot 1
```

Answer (score -6):

1. get iso country code => US
2. lookup this table => 1
   https://countrycode.org/

Comment: Please fully understand the question before trying to provide answer.